# Limits of a probability

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How could I show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}P(A_n)= 0$$
Where $$A_n$$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint events.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If they are disjoint, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n) \le 1$.

Comment: If a series of non negative number converge to a number that is lower than 1 it means that the only possible convergence is to 0, and therefore every element P(An)  is equal to 0 and so also his limits. Is it correct the reasoning? What I don't understand is how a arrived to the summation, or better, I know that the union of An is equal to omega, and therefore the probability must be lower than 1, but why I have to take the union of the An? This problem ask me the limit of the probability, where it imply the union of sets?

Comment: $\sigma$-additivity is one of the [axioms of probability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms):  If $A_n$ are disjoint, $P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)$.

Comment: yes of course, but why have I to take the Union?

Comment: There are only a limited number of operations available to you in this problem.  Union is one of them, and it works.  If you can find another that works, you can use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a contrary. Then, there exists some positive $\varepsilon$ and increasing (and infinite) sequence of positive integers $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $P(A_{n_k})\geq\varepsilon$ for each positive integer $k$. However, $A_{n_k}$ are disjoint events and so $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}P(A_{n_k})\leq 1$ which impossible since $P(A_{n_k})\geq\varepsilon>0$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Ok this I get it, thank you! could you also read my comment to Robert and help me to resolve that doubt (since you also used the summation)?